# Visual Studio moving a solution to a folder in the repo

Tags: visual-studio

My solution is currently in the root of a DevOps repo, is it possible to move it (and it's full contents) into a folder in the repo, maintaining the structure and links to Visual Studio source control?

In the future I need to maintain several solutions in the same repo and so want them all in separate folders.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Why don't you do it, update the solution file with the new locations, and see what breaks?

Comment: But that doesn't move the solution file in the repo or any of the projects / project files

Comment: I don't understand your problem: what's stopping you from opening up File Explorer, right clicking the solution file, clicking Cut, then moving to the place you want the solution file to be at, right clicking, clicking Paste? Or whatever other way you like to use to move files?

Comment: That will only move things locally, not in the repo

Answer (score 0):

If you use TFVC, you can use this way: [Rename or move files and folders in TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/rename-move-files-folders?view=azure-devops).

For GIT, just move locally and commit/push changes. In this case, git performs 2 operations: delete a project from an old folder and add it to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

After much trying and hair pulling, going to the folder view in Visual Studio allowed the files in the solution to be moved.